# Python class structure

Tags: python

I am trying to make my new code as user friendly as possible and what I would have in mind for the particular problem I am facing atm is this:

Suppose we have

```
import numpy as np

class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @property
    def method_a(self):
        return np.median(self.data)

    @property
    def method_b(self):
        return np.mean(self.data)

foo = TestClass([1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 6, 3, 37, 16])
print(foo.method_a)
print(foo.method_b)
```

Everything is fine so far. Method A gives me the median, method B the mean.

During processing I will switch depending on circumstances between both methods. So sometimes I will call method A, sometimes method B. 
However, what I want is then to continue with a method C, that acts upon the result of either method A or B in such a way

```
final_result = foo.method_a.method_c
```

or

```
final_result = foo.method_b.method_c
```

I know it is possible to write method C as a function and do it like this:

```
final_result = method_c(foo.method_a)
final_result = method_c(foo.method_b)
```

but I think it would make the code easier to read if I could apply method C as stated above.

Is this possible somehow?

thanks

Comment: what do you want to do? if you are trying to process the result of `mean` and `median`, why not wrap it first before returning?

Comment: The mean and median calculations are actually just a placeholder here for much more complicated functions I have implemented myself. Method A does some calculations; method B also, but a little different. The type of the result is always the same. Not sure how wrapping the functions would get me what I want. Can you think of a simple example?

Comment: Do you ever want to call `method_a` or `method_b` without then calling `method_c` on the result?

Comment: Consider that right now, `method_a` and `method_b` are returning a simple number, and `method_c` would take that number as a parameter. Your proposed change would mean making a whole new class, or adding state to `TestClass`, just to enable call-chaining. You would be adding complexity to the implementation of the method, for what's a very debatable increase in readability of the call. Personally, I prefer using parameters and return values over object state whenever appropriate. The rules are a little different at API surfaces, but to make an API friendly you'd ideally only expose one method.

Answer (score 2):

your statement is not quite clear, let's assume you want to add method C to the class. you can wrap your return value inside of the class again to achieve what you want:

```
import numpy as np

class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, _data):
        self._data = data

    @property
    def data(self): return self._data

    @property
    def method_a(self):
        return TestClass(np.median(self.data))

    @property
    def method_b(self):
        return TestClass(np.mean(self.data))

    @property
    def method_c(self):
        return TestClass(np.whatever(self.data))
```

then you can chain however long you want:

```
final_result = foo.method_a.method_b.method_c.method_c.data
```

if the class is not what you plan to place, you put different one.

Comment: Humm. I did not manage to implement your ideas directly in my code, however, I dd not know that one can wrap a return value inside another class.  With this I simply moved my Methods A and B to the parenting class and returned a new class for which then method C can be applied in the way I want. Hard to describe what I did, but your comment helped 

Answer (score 0):

Following HuStmpHrrr's comment I changed my code like this
(Here I just assume that method C simply adds 1 to the results):

```
import numpy as np

class NewClass:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def method_c(self):
        return self.data + 1

class TestClass:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    @property
    def method_a(self):
        return NewClass(np.median(self.data))

    @property
    def method_b(self):
        return NewClass(np.mean(self.data))

foo = TestClass([1, 2, 5, 7, 12, 6, 3, 37, 16])

result1 = foo.method_a
result2 = foo.method_b
print(result1.method_c())
print(result2.method_c())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want a property. Your code seems like it really just needs a simple method. Properties are for data that you would get and set that you want to manage.

```
class Test(Object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        super().__init__()

        self.data = data
        self.value = 0
    # end Constructor

    def method_a(self):
        return np.median(self.data)
    # end method_a

    @property
    def method_c(self):
        return self.value
    @method_c.setter
    def method_c(self, value):
        self.value = value
        # self.method_a(value)
    # end method_c
# end class Test

t = Test([1,2,3,4])
print(t.method_a())
t.method_c = 5 # This calls the method_c.setter and will make t.value = 5
print(t.method_c)
```

The property is typically used as a wrapper method to control the data.